# Site icon is very similar to Astronomy.SE

Tags: discussion, design

The icon for the site is very similar / identical to that of [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com). On my iPad, the extra horizontal line is not visible; on my MacBook, with a Retina screen, I can see the font is slightly different but not much more:

[image]

Even at 200% zoom (click on the image to view it) the difference is minimal.

Can it be changed to something else (perhaps ADA to be consistent with other blockchain sites on the network, though other suggestions are welcome).

A similar case from the past: [Favicon of Earth Science and Spanish are too similar (exactly the same in HNQ list)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285456/295232)

Comment: Congrats on the very first Cardano Meta question, Glorf ;)

Comment: On Google Chrome on my desktop, I see the two horizontal lines, maybe your title can be more specific to say that this is an iPad (or Safari/Apple) problem?

Comment: So... is it *only* the similarity to Astronomy that's the problem? Because that feels less like a problem considering y'all have a Unicode character that directly relates to your subject - like how Chess has a rook or Bricks a brick. In my experience, three-letter (full-width) characters look really squished on the icons so I'd be concerned that "ADA" may be hard to read.

Comment: Why not use the Cardano logo for the icon? Wouldn't that make sense? Or is there any copyright issue?

Comment: @IngoH would be nice, but it's not a Unicode symbol: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339853/295232 Perhaps there's a similar one though?

Answer (score 0):

Most people will not see both icons.  I agree that a logo change would be nice but something to address in future rather than right now.

Answer (score 0):

I would make more sense to use the Cardano logo

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the question, we only allow the use of Unicode characters. We would not use a logo.