# What about better Icon more releated to https://cardano.org/?

Tags: discussion

What about better Icon more releated to https://cardano.org/ as this icon not readable and very similar to other sites in Stack Exchange Network?

My Question is different. Beacause [Site icon is very similar to Astronomy.SE](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/site-icon-is-very-similar-to-astronomy-se) mean it similar to another site but I mean it is too dark in browser dark mode So Sadly this does not answer my question.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for which icon to use?

Comment: @NikeDattani Actually No , but what about the official icon of https://cardano.org/ .. I see it a bit good

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will be entertained because unless it's a unicode character. Sites don't get custom designs unless there's a sponsor, or the site becomes very mature (usually takes several years: Etherium.SE and Bitcoin.SE do not even have custom designs yet!).

Comment: @NikeDattani Ok Bitcoin have icon that have written "B C" So what about make icon be like "C A" or any other character that make readabilty better but I am new in SE So I do not know how to change icon of sites .. OK

Comment: You could suggest "CA" as a logo in the Meta question and see how the community feels about it!

Comment: @NikeDattani OK .. No problem we will keep icon as it is. but what about make icon other color in meta than dark beacause in Browser Dark Mode it make everything worse!

Comment: Such changes are very unlikely to be entertained just for this tiny Private Beta site (these are problems with the entire SE Network, not just Cardano.SE). You might want to search on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) if someone else has previously complained about the issue in the browser's darkmode.

Comment: @NikeDattani Sure but what about make site better (I know we tiny but in future this will change .. Right) Ok I will search .. If you found any similar question tell me out .. Thanks Nike Dattani